# How to map a function to all elements of a namedtuple?

Tags: python-3.x

I have some `namedtuple` which I want to apply a function on its members and then create a new `namedtuple` with the processed elements of the same name.

```
from collections import namedtuple

def fun(val):
    if val is None:
        return "Unknown"
    return f"'{val}'"
```

I tried a basic map to the constructor but I don't know the elements or type of the `namedtuple`

```
processed_tuple = namedtuple(map(fun, some_tuple))
```

or

```
processed_tuple = namedtuple(*map(fun, some_tuple))
```

do not work.

`some_tuple` is constructed at runtime and can have different fieldnames. For example a person but I don't know that before:

```
Person = namedtuple("Person", ["Firstname", "Lastname"])
some_tuple = Person("Foo", None)
```

The processed `namedtuple` should then look like `(Firstname="'Foo'", Lastname="Unknown")`

Is there a generic approach or do I have to know the members before hand?

Comment: post a representative `some_tuple`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I added an example tuple but at program runtime I don't know how the `namedtuple` looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not fully sure if this is what you want:

```
from inspect import signature
from collections import namedtuple

Person = namedtuple("Person", ["Firstname", "Lastname"])
some_tuple = Person("Foo", None)

def fun(val):
    if val is None:
        return "Unknown"
    return f"'{val}'"

processed_tuple = namedtuple('X', signature(type(some_tuple)).parameters
                             )._make(map(fun, some_tuple))
```

Or:

```
processed_tuple = namedtuple('X', some_tuple._fields
                             )._make(map(fun, some_tuple))
```

Output:

```
X(Firstname="'Foo'", Lastname='Unknown')
```

Comment: Not quiet there, the result tuple should be `(Firstname="'Foo'", Lastname="Unknown")`

Comment: Great, but I don't know the type `Person` at programming time. I get *any* and different tuples.

Comment: Yes you do, yo can use `signature(type(some_tuple))` or actually `some_tuple._fields` ;)